# Replacing a dynamic url with text?

Tags: regex, replace, regex-greedy

I need to replace the below url (including img tags) with text. I am not very good with regex...

However, as the date will change its not only about copy and replace infortunately.

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)">
```

and sometimes with class="wp-smiley"

```
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)" class="wp-smiley" />
```

So any time this image is posted I want the complete string to replaced to text ";)"

Its a site built in Wordpress using PHP

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I want to clarify why I can not just use a search and replace and why the url is dynamic.

The date part - written as this /2012/10/ will be different for every time this image is posted. **So everything but the date will be the same all the time!!**

And saometime the string ends with **alt=";)">** and sometimes with **class="wp-smiley" />**

Comment: A regular expression by itself is only used to match text, if you just want to match one static URL (since it seems this image will always have this URL...) then the match is simply the text `"http://thailand..."` etc... perhaps you should refine your question and tell us what variations you want to match

Comment: Hi and thanks,i am so sorry that I was unclear when I wrote that the only thing that will change is the date.

Answer (score 1):

This should match your URL and any date (at least until 2099)

```
 http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20\d\d/\d+/icon_wink\.gif
```

Comment: Hi Ben, It did not work as I got the following error message: 
Invalid regular expression: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

And when I try with forward slash as delimeters I get another error
Invalid regular expression: Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: If your error has to do with delimiters then you have an issue not with the pattern but with how you are using it and you should post some code to give context as to how you are applying the pattern

Comment: Hi, I am using this plug in. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/screenshots/

I found out @ should be used as delimeter. However, doing a search in content nothing was found, which was strange?

Comment: I think I am getting at it now :)
However, the full string was not identified as I need tags as well, do you mind :O
<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/icon_wink.gif" alt=";)" class="wp-smiley" />

I have updated my original post with what was missing in your expression. Would much appreaciate a last shot at this :)

Comment: This one is almost working: @<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20\d\d/\d+/icon_smile\d+\.gif.*\s/>@
However when the class="wp-smiley" /> is not included in the end it does not stop at alt=";)"> meaning I get to many tags included: like gif" alt=":)"></p><br /><br /> 
Note I am now using a image name that change, smile1 smile2 etc,. but I think I solved that one

Comment: you dont mind to give it a second shoot now when I have the infomation gathered?

Comment: `<img src="http://thailandsbloggare.se/wp-content/uploads/20\d\d/\d+/icon_wink\.gif" [^>]+>` should match the link if the only thing that can change is the date, and the possibility of other html attributes appearing after src